# Webpacker confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, assets, webpacker

I implemented Webpack into my Rails app a few months back and have it compiling and organising my JS, CSS, Images, SVGs and fonts all correctly and renaming them when required.

Now Webpacker is available and more integrated into Rails I basically have two questions:

Where do all the compiled files get placed? My current Webpack setup outputs them all to /public and I can see them all in there. Where does Webpacker put them?

Where do I put any of the custom configuration for Webpacker? Eg: to deal with Sass, images, svg's and fonts etc?

Thanks

Edit:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'application': [
      './app/assets/scripts/application.js',
      './app/assets/styles/application.scss'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'assets', 'application'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/assets/application/'
  },
  watch: false,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader?url=true', { loader:"resolve-url-loader", options: { debug: true} }, 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=svg/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]'
      }
      // {
      //   test: /\.css$/,
      //   use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      //     use: 'css-loader'
      //   })
      // }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      '$': 'jquery',
      'window.$': 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      'jquery': 'jquery',
      'window.jquery': 'jquery'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css'),
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: '.',
      manifest: require('./public/assets/vendor/json/vendor.json')
    }),
  ]
};
```

Comment: after running `bundle exec rails webpacker:install` you will get some configuration file in your config/webpack and a yaml file config/webpacker.yml. You can easily set the output path in the yaml file.

Comment: @DonaldChiang Ok, That's all fine but i've added in my question my original webpack config.   How do I do all the things i'm doing there but in Webpacker? Eg, the images, svgs, fonts etc?

Comment: If you want to add loaders and plugins to webpacker you can add custom js file in config/webpack or just modify config/webpack/development.js to add them.
You can read webpacker github docs here: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md

Answer (score 0):

I had some images I used in *app/assets/stylesheets/applications.scss* in Rails 5. I got an error when I switched to Rails 6 with Webpacker.

I got them to work by

1. making two directories: *app/javascript/images/* and *app/javascript/styles/*
2. addind `import('styles/application.css')` to *app/javascript/packs/application.js*.
3. making a new file, *app/javascript/styles/application.css*, and moving my CSS to it
4. moving the images to the *app/javascript/images/* folder
5. changing the url in *app/javascript/styles/application.css* to `backgound-image: image-url("../images/image.png");`

I hope this helps.